# Using numpys interp right

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation

I've got a list with resistances(self.interp_data[:,0])  and the corresponding temperatures(self.interp_data[:,1]). I would like to determine the temperature from my measured resistance using the interp function in numpy. This is my function:

```
def calc_T(self, V_out, V_g, R_ref):
    R_T = np.array([(V_g * R_ref/ V_out) - R_ref])
    print R_T
    print type( self.interp_data[0,0])
    print type( self.interp_data[0,1])
    print bisect_right(self.interp_data[:,0], R_T)
    print self.interp_data[:,0] < R_T
    return np.interp(R_T, self.interp_data[:,0],self.interp_data[:,1] )
```

This is the result:

```
[ 22549.01960784]
<type 'numpy.float64'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
211
[False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
[ 150.]
```

This list contains 211 elements and the last element has the value 150. So bisect and interp both agree that R_T  is smaller than the smallest resistance value in the list.

But the comparison revels that it is somewhere in between and I agree. How do I use interp correctly to get the temperature corresponding to my measured resistance?

Comment: to get this working correctly, `self.interp_data[:,0]` must be sorted...

Comment: You're right. The array had descending array. Now it work. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `xp` input of `np.interp(x, xp, fp)` must be sorted. Considering that, your example should work doing:

```
a = self.interp_data[:,0]
b = self.interp_data[:,1]

argsa = np.argsort(a)
xp = np.take(a, argsa)
fp = np.take(b, argsa)
np.interp(R_T, xp, fp)
```

Comment: It would be more constructive if the downvoter could let a comment... what is wrong with this approach?